# Framework for algorithmic decision process

Tags: .net, rule-engine, expert-system

I am looking for a framework to allow the following:

- Implement several algorithms that take as input one or more collections of simple classes (POCO), and result in a new list of POCOs
- Each algorithm is generally looking at various attributes of the input collections, and how they relate to each other.
- An important requirement is that the algorithm needs to be expressed in a manageable way, allowing easy maintenance and changes
- Nice to have: a way to allow the user to maintain the algorithm

I maybe looking for a Rules engine, an expert system implementation, a classifier algorithm or some combination of those.

Update: The rules may be quite complex, e.g. if there is a match between 3 objects in the first collection and 2 in the second, then search for a match for the third, mismatched object in the second collection and an object in a third collection.  The matching rules may be defined in delegated functions.

Any ideas?

I live and work in the .Net world :-)

Comment: I do not think this is a fair comment @Mitch.  I am not looking for a book or IDE accommodation, rather for an idea, possibly a framework, that will help me progress with a very real problem.  I see dozens of similar questions posted and answered everyday on this site.

Comment: Did you read the posts at that link? SO is not here to decide on which framework you should be using. That's YOUR job!

Comment: I beg to differ - saying that answering a question is the  job of the person who asked it can be applied to many other questions here.  The point of SO is to benefit from other people's experience and knowledge if they wish to share it.  I suggest you move along.

Comment: You can beg to differ all you like. It won't change the fact that this is not a suitable question for SO. Moving along...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several rule engines for .NET. [Drools](http://droolsdotnet.codehaus.org/), in its .NET version, is not one I would recommend. One of the best ones I know is [NxBRE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nxbre/). However that project has been dormant for quite a while. The [WWF rule engine](http://www.richard-banks.org/2007/08/how-to-use-windows-workflow-rules.html) might be an option for you.

Comment: The post about using the WWF rule engine on its own is probably the direction i will take.  Thanks!

Comment: @David Brabant: The post about using the WWF rule engine that you linked to references sample code for creating a rules editor, but the link is broken. Do you have any recommendations about how to enter and store rules (without the workflow editor)?

Comment: @GilShalit: any update on whether this approach was successful for you? or how you ultimately solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that I completely understand the rules that you're explaining in your "Update" section but have you checked out the [Enigma Rules Engine](http://www.enigmasupercomputing.com/RulesEngine)?

It's a simple, deterministic (non-RETE) rules engine that I created to run against POCO objects and has a relatively easy-to-use interface (for non-programmers). It is based on Windows Workflow so there are built in activities for iterating through collections, evaluating expressions, and you can create your own activity classes, etc. Passing in and out arguments that are collections is a piece of cake.

Comment: I will have to see what the advantage is over the standard WWF rule engine.  Thanks!